# then promise Angular 7 - 'then' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the following function to update an array in Firestore:

**component.ts**

```
crearFavorito(key, e) {
    this.fs.addFavorito(key);
    this.snackBar.open(this.message, this.action, {
      duration: 3000,
    });
  }
```

**service.ts**

```
addFavorito(key) {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.afs.doc('eventos/' + key).update({
      favoritos: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(user.uid)
    });
  }
```

This works well when the user is authenticated, but when there is no user logged in I get the following error in the console:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

Given this what I want to do is redirect it to my login section or show a message that must be authenticated, then I tried the following:

**component.ts**

```
crearFavorito(key, e) {
    this.fs.addFavorito(key)
    .then(() => {
      this.snackBar.open(this.message, this.action, {
        duration: 3000,
      });
    }, error => console.error('error:', error));
  }
```

But I get the following error in `then` Typescript:

> 'then' does not exist on type 'void'

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: `addFavorito` does not `return` anything, so for typescript, the type of the function is `void`. You need to return a promise.

Comment: `addFavorito` doesn't return anything; it's unclear why you expected a different outcome.

Comment: Please read the error message and use `debugger;` to inspect your source code before you ask a question. It would really help to improve the quality of questions on this website.

Answer (score 0):

simply add `return` in front of the update call. Here is the updated code

```
addFavorito(key) {
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  return this.afs.doc('eventos/' + key).update({
    favoritos: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(user.uid)
  });
}
```

For the `crearFavorito` function to be able to handle the promise, `addFavorito` needs to return a promise first. Luckily, the document update function of Firebase already returns a promise. So, all you need to do is return it again.